# SASS variables not parsing correctly - Undefined variable: "$ct-white"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

I am using SASS for the first time, and my variables seem to have stopped working.  I have the following code in my `application.css.scss` file:

```
*= require_self
*/
@import "layout";
@import "colors";
...
@import "text";
```

In my partial `_colors.css.scss` file, there is:

```
...
$ct-white: #F8F8F8 !global;
```

and in my partial `_layout.css.scss` file (the Rails default layout file):

```
/* Site-wide layout syntax */
body {
  background-color: $ct-white;
}
```

I know that the `_layout.css.scss` file is loading because other styles on the page work fine when I set `body { background-color: #F8F8F8; }`.  For some reason, the variable isn't being parsed correctly.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing `colors` after `layout` , so the variables you define in `colors` are not available for `layout`. You could simply invert the order of those two lines. In SASS, import order matters.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `sass-rails` gem, [it uses sass 3.2.0](https://gemnasium.com/rails/sass-rails) so `!global` throws an error.

Comment: I did not know that.  I had included in there to show that it was an option I already explored, but thanks!

Comment: While this is true for older Sass versions, the existence of the `!global` flag does not raise an "Undefined variable" error as indicated by the OP.